# nix-env: understading available attribute paths in the active Nix expression

Tags: nix

In my NixOS machine, I can use [`nix-env`](https://www.mankier.com/1/nix-env) to query about the `ghc` package in two ways:

One is `nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -qaP ghc` which results in the output

```
ghc  ghc-8.6.5
```

Another is `nix-env -qaP ghc` which results in the output

```
nixpkgs.ghc  ghc-8.6.5
```

For the second case, I would like to understand why the active Nix expression has a `nixpkgs` root attribute.

The contents of the `~/.nix-defexpr` folder and several subfolders are the following:

[image]

How is the active Nix expression assembled from the contents of `~/.nix-defexpr`? Why there isn't a `channels` root attribute? Does the name of the `nixpkgs` root attribute derive from the name of the `nixpkgs` folder, or is it derived from the contents of the folder, perhaps from something declared in the `default.nix` file?

Comment: Awesome detective work, and the examples are highly educational! This has baffled me for years, still I just went with the flow, but now I understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#files) has some info on how `.nix-defexpr` is assembled:

> The Nix expressions in this directory are combined into a single set,
>   with each file as an attribute that has the name of the file.

It doesn't mention what happens if the contents are themselves directories, though. But I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/487) that explains things a little more:

> - If a directory is a valid expression (i.e. has default.nix) its expression will be added to the set, otherwise it will be traversed
>     recursively.
> - Names of intermediate directories are completely ignored (i.e. do not take any part in attrpaths).
> - manifest.nix is recursively ignored.

So, there isn't a `channels` root attribute because the folder doesn't have a `default.nix` expression.

Ok. Then, as an experiment, I created a folder `.nix-defexpr/foo` with a file `default.nix` with contents `{ zzz = 4; }` inside. When I execute `nix-env --install -A foo.zzz` I get:

```
error: expression does not evaluate to a derivation (or a set or list of those)
```

Which means that it actually found the path! The problem is that `4` is not a derivation.

But what if I create another folder `.nix-defexpr/whatever` and put a copy of the folder `foo` there? Won't there be some kind of name collision? Yes, there is:

```
8f792ff4f96a:~# nix-env --install -A foo.zzz
warning: name collision in input Nix expressions, skipping '/root/.nix-defexpr/whatever/foo'
```